# OpenApi: how to describe error codes and messages?

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I'd like to provide a series of custom codes and message for my error 400 but can't find any way to do so.
Ideally something like:

```
Error:
  type: object
  enum:
    - [E01, 'Error1']
    - [E02, 'Error2']
```

And so on

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure that enums here can help you.
If you take a look over official documentation Enums are just strings, not object https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/ .

So my proposal is to use :

```
ErrorType:
 type: object
 properties:
   code: 
     type: integer
   name:
     type: string
 example:   # Sample object
     code: 10
     name: Custom Error

 Error:
  type: object
  properties:
     errors:
       oneOf:
         - $ref '#/ErrorType'
         - etc...
or directly without properties
Error:
  type: object
  oneOf:
   - $ref '#/ErrorType'
   - etc...
```

You can take a look for more examples on the official page https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/

Answer (score 1):

You can check out how `Twitter` has described it with `$oneOf` ( https://api.twitter.com/labs/2/openapi.json ) but unfortunately this convention is not easy nor supported by code generation tools like `openapi-generator`.

Until OpenApi supports enum descriptions (proposal is pending), one of the easiest ways are to:

1. define enum with all possible error codes
2. in the top level `description:` section of the spec define an inner section (with markdown notation `#Error codes`) that lists all error codes along with description.
3. Automated tool should check if the enum and description is consistent.

Comment: The link is no longer available. In the future, please quote relevant bits of the linked page into your answer for posterity in line with https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.